# kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable in celery

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery, fastapi, celery-task

I am having a fast API where I am using celery for task queue predictions. whenever I am doing predictions and trying to return a response I am getting `500 Undocumented Error: Internal Server Error` and receiving an error from docker logs

```py
[2022-04-18 10:49:51,965: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redis:6379/0
[2022-04-18 10:49:51,969: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2022-04-18 10:49:52,980: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2022-04-18 10:49:53,044: INFO/MainProcess] celery@809b6efd8550 ready.
[2022-04-18 10:49:55,704: INFO/MainProcess] Task create_task[efcc7e7e-4fea-4c2d-b135-8aa546418327] received
[2022-04-18 10:50:05,748: ERROR/ForkPoolWorker-8] Task create_task[efcc7e7e-4fea-4c2d-b135-8aa546418327] raised unexpected: EncodeError(TypeError('Object of type set is not JSON serializable'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 39, in _reraise_errors
yield
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 210, in dumps
payload = encoder(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 68, in dumps
return _dumps(s, cls=cls or _default_encoder,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
return cls(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 58, in default
return super().default(o)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 517, in trace_task
mark_as_done(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 161, in mark_as_done
self.store_result(task_id, result, state, request=request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 482, in store_result
self._store_result(task_id, result, state, traceback,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 909, in _store_result
self._set_with_state(self.get_key_for_task(task_id), self.encode(meta), state)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 372, in encode
_, _, payload = self._encode(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 376, in _encode
return dumps(data, serializer=self.serializer)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 210, in dumps
payload = encoder(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/contextlib.py", line 131, in __exit__
self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 43, in _reraise_errors
reraise(wrapper, wrapper(exc), sys.exc_info()[2])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/exceptions.py", line 21, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 39, in _reraise_errors
yield
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 210, in dumps
payload = encoder(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 68, in dumps
return _dumps(s, cls=cls or _default_encoder,
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 234, in dumps
return cls(
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kombu/utils/json.py", line 58, in default
return super().default(o)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
```

No idea why I am getting this error.

`My worker.py`

```py
@celery.task(name='create_task')
def create_task(solute, solvent):
    time.sleep(10)
    return {'Harsha'}
```

`main.py`

```py
@app.get(api_names[0])
async def predict(solute,solvent):
    task = create_task.delay(solute,solvent)
    return JSONResponse({'task_id': task.id})

@app.get('/predict_solubility/{task_id}')
async def post(task_id):
    task_result = AsyncResult(task_id)
    result = {
        'task_id': task_id,
        'task_status': task_result.status,
        'task_result' : task_result
    }
    return result
```

`prediction`

```py
response = {}
async def predictions(solute, solvent):
    response.clear()
    m = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solute,sanitize=False)
    n = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solvent,sanitize=False)
    if (m == None or n == None):
      response['predictions']= 'invalid SMILES'
      print('invalid SMILES')
    else:
      mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solute)
      mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
      solute = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)
      solute_graph = get_graph_from_smile(solute)
      mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(solvent)
      mol = Chem.AddHs(mol)
      solvent = Chem.MolToSmiles(mol)
      solvent_graph = get_graph_from_smile(solvent)
      delta_g, interaction_map =  model([solute_graph.to(device), solvent_graph.to(device)])
      interaction_map_one = torch.trunc(interaction_map)
      response["interaction_map"] = (interaction_map_one.detach().numpy()).tolist()
      response["predictions"] = delta_g.item()
```

[screen shot of the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjaTo.png)

Comment: Store the result and task status in database and create a fetching endpoint to get it task when task is completed

Comment: @sudden_appearance I didn't understood your comment. If your mentioning about the `time.sleep(10)`  i am just using as an example and receiving failed as status

Comment: The task can not return a set. Try with a list!

Comment: @KlausD. it also depends if he uses `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND`, if he doesn't use `RabbitMQ` as broker, as it doesn't return results. Storing to database is the simplest way I can imagine

Comment: @sudden_appearance I am using redis as broker

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks it solved the issue. but when i remove the string and adding function to return prediction response i am getting errror `kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type coroutine is not JSON serializable` .  This is the function i am taking about  ```@celery.task(name='create_task')
 def create_task(solute, solvent):
 p = predictions(solute, solvent)
 return [p]```

Answer (score 1):

To explain what the error message actually means: there is no data type matching a set in JSON - i.e. Python's `Set()` can't be represented in JSON, so when the task result is serialized to JSON to be returned, an error will be thrown instead.

If you see the code in your task, you're returning a set:

```
def create_task(solute, solvent):
    time.sleep(10)
    return {'Harsha'}
```

The `{value}` syntax creates a set in Python. You might have thought that you returned a dictionary, but that needs to either be empty or have at least one `key: value` pair to be created as a dict (otherwise, a set is created - if there's only a single value or multiple values without a key).

```
return {'result': 'Harsha'}
```

.. would have returned a dictionary instead.